# How to enable monetization for youtube videos automatically using youtube data api in JAVA?

Tags: youtube-data-api

How to enable monetization automatically for youtube videos. I am trying with below code which is not working:

```java
VideoMonetizationDetails videoMonetizationDetail = new  videoMonetizationDetails();
AccessPolicy accessPolicy = new AccessPolicy();
accessPolicy.setAllowed(true);
videoMonetizationDetail.setAccess(accessPolicy);
ytvideo.setMonetizationDetails(videoMonetizationDetail);
```

Showing below error:

> ```
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> ```

Is there any way to automatically enable monetization for youtube videos???

Comment: That is a network error. You need to resolve it first.

Comment: But when I commented out this code then it works well and upload videos on youtube. This error comes only with monetization code.

Answer (score 0):

This is for LiveStream

```
LiveBroadcast broadcast = youtube.liveBroadcasts().get("id,snippet,contentDetails,status", LIVE_STREAM_ID).execute();
LiveBroadcastSnippet snippet = broadcast.getSnippet();
LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = broadcast.getContentDetails();
LiveBroadcastStatus status = broadcast.getStatus();

// Enable monetization for the live stream
contentDetails.setEnableMonetization(true);

// Set the ad formats and ad breaks for the live stream
contentDetails.setAdFormats(Arrays.asList("display", "overlay", "skippable"));
SlateSettings slateSettings = new SlateSettings();
VideoAdDetails videoAdDetails = new VideoAdDetails();
List<VideoAdDetails.BreakPosition> breakPositions = Arrays.asList(
    new VideoAdDetails.BreakPosition().setPosition(30),
    new VideoAdDetails.BreakPosition().setPosition(60),
    new VideoAdDetails.BreakPosition().setPosition(90));
videoAdDetails.setBreakPositions(breakPositions);
slateSettings.setVideoAdDetails(videoAdDetails);
contentDetails.setSlateSettings(slateSettings);

// Update the live broadcast with the new monetization settings
LiveBroadcast broadcastUpdate = new LiveBroadcast()
    .setSnippet(snippet)
    .setContentDetails(contentDetails)
    .setStatus(status);
youtube.liveBroadcasts().update("id,snippet,contentDetails,status", broadcastUpdate).execute();
 }
}
```